# PHP arrayObject why cannot I access array keys using object notation?

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I'm trying to access array keys via object notation. I thought code below should work?

```
<?php

  $accountData = array('role'=> 'user');
  $accountDataAO = new ArrayObject($accountData, ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
  echo $accountDataAO->role;
?>
```

But I get this:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: ArrayObject::$role in /home/stan/Desktop/test.php on line 5
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/stan/Desktop/test.php:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From php.net `This class allows objects to work as arrays.` ==> not arrays as objects. Eitherway, check the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Comment: ohh nvm. I figured it out. Had to add: ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS

Comment: @Dannyboy update your original question then in case anyone else searches for the same thing.

Comment: @Styphon i've added it as an answer.

Comment: For future reference, this is demonstrated on the [`ArrayObject::setFlags()` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.setflags.php).

Answer (score 3):

ahh. nvm. I had to add: ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS

```
<?php
  $accountData = array('role'=> 'user');
  $accountDataAO = new ArrayObject($accountData, ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST | ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS); 
  echo $accountDataAO->role;
?>
```